# Storing an input as a variable then trying to extract as string with regex is giving error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Tags: python-3.x

This might be something simple but I cannot seem to find the answer.
I want to input a date in DD/MM/YY then use regex to extract only the numbers.

In = 22/02/21
Out = 22022021

Here is my example:

```
sd = input('Add date (DD/MM/YY): ')
fn = sd.str.extract(r'(\d)')
```

However I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<dir>/example.py", line 2, in <module>
    fn = sd.str.extract(r'(\d)') 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Any insight on why this is happening would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You seem to be assuming `sd` is some sort of pandas value. It's not. It's just a bare Python string.Those don't have a `str` nor `extract` method.

Comment: Did you mean `re.findall(r"\d", sd)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks deceze, got tunnel vision as this is from a bigger project I have been working on involving pandas.. Here is what I used instead:

```
sd = input('Add date (DD/MM/YY): ')

>>> 02/02/20

fn = sd.replace('/','')

print(fn)

>>> 020220
```